# Execute parallel functions and wait for all results on PHP web page

Tags: php, api, concurrency, parallel-processing

we have a (synchronous, at present) PHP web page which sequentially calls around 25 functions and each of them calls in turn an external API. Since each API requires a few seconds to get answered, the page load time is around 1 minute and a half.

I was looking for a way to call all functions in parallel to shorten this long time. I had a look at PThreads which doesn't seem to fit (it's a web based environment). Also using pcntl_fork seem pretty messy to me.

Is there anything recommended that we could use to accomplish this task?

Thank you!

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094698/php-send-post-request-in-separate-thread-and-forget?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Gearman is a generic application framework for farming out work to multiple machines or processes. It allows applications to complete tasks in parallel, to load balance processing, and to call functions between languages. The framework can be used in a variety of applications, from high-availability web sites to the transport of database replication events.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer Uzair, I'll check it to see if it can be used on our env